# Failed to install an apk file programmatically

Tags: java, android

I programmatically downloaded an apk file from my Google Drive. Every time I try to install it programmatically it just says something like "Application has not been installed" (I translated it). I compared the checksums of the original and the downloaded file to see if the downloaded file is corrupt, but it's not.

Logcat does not print any information about that.
This is how I try to install it:

```
    @Override
    public void onUpdateDownloaded(String path) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: This now has an answer by the original poster, seems OK to me (unless it's a dupe).

Answer (score 2):

Fixed the problem: I was just trying to install an app with a lower version, which brought about the issue.

Comment: @MikeStockdale - you are mistaken.  This is the resolution to the *problem behind* the question asked, **posted by the very person who asked it**.

Comment: You don't have to apologize for posting an answer. Neither do you have to note it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It probably will not work with `Uri.fromFile(new File(path))`.

First copy apk file to sd card programmatically and then

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() 
+ "/yourApplication.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```